# Android studio push notification error

Tags: java, android, android-activity, android-notifications

I have following Compiler error:

> Annotation are not allowed here

error on the line

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            public void make (View view){ ..
```

any idea? i am creating a message notification using android link with firebase.,

```
package com.example.mypc.thisissample;

    import android.annotation.TargetApi;
    import android.app.Notification;
    import android.app.NotificationManager;
    import android.app.PendingIntent;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Build;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import com.firebase.client.Firebase;

    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        private EditText editText;
        private ListView listView;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
            final Firebase firebase = new Firebase("https://sample.firebaseio.com/");


            editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
            listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

            listView.setAdapter(new MessageAdapter(this, Message.class, R.layout.fragment_message, firebase.child("chat")));

            Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

            button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Message message = new Message();

                    message.setMessage(editText.getText().toString());
                    message.setAuthor("Name");

                    firebase.child("Chat").push().setValue(message);

                    editText.setText("");
                }
            });

            @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
            public void make (View view){

                Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayNotification.class);
                PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

                Notification notifications = new Notification.Builder(this)
                        .setContentTitle("New notification like message from")
                        .setContentText("Hii").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                        .setContentIntent(pending)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.reply, "Reply", pending)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.cancel, "cancel", pending)
                        .addAction(R.drawable.settings, "settings", pending).build();

                NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
                notifications.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                manager.notify(0, notifications);

            }

        }
    }
```

Comment: put your function outside of your `oncreate`

Answer (score 1):

> Actually the problem is not with the `annotation`.

You cant create **a function inside another function**. Your function `public void make(View view)` is inside the `onCreate`. So just put it outside of the `onCreate` Function.

**You can't do this**

```
protected void Test() {
        public void anotherFunction() {

        }
    }
```

**You have to do this in this way**

```
protected void Test() {
}

public void anotherFunction() {

}
```

Answer (score 0):

`@TargetApi` does not prevent any code from being run, it is merely for annotating code and preventing compiler errors for new APIs

You can try using this inside your `void make(View view)` method like this:

```
public void make (View view){
  if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN){
            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayNotification.class);
            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

            Notification notifications = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("New notification like message from")
                    .setContentText("Hii").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                    .setContentIntent(pending)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.reply, "Reply", pending)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.cancel, "cancel", pending)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.settings, "settings", pending).build();

            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notifications.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            manager.notify(0, notifications);
  }else {
   //your code for supporting pre-jellybean devices
  }
           
}
```

**EDIT1:**

Try to move your `void make(View view)` method outside `onCreate()` method like this code to solve this issue or use above code and check how to show notification for lower version than jelly-bean:

```
package com.example.mypc.thisissample;

import android.annotation.TargetApi;
import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.PendingIntent;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListView;

import com.firebase.client.Firebase;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private EditText editText;
    private ListView listView;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        Firebase.setAndroidContext(this);
        final Firebase firebase = new Firebase("https://sample.firebaseio.com/");


        editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);

        listView.setAdapter(new MessageAdapter(this, Message.class, R.layout.fragment_message, firebase.child("chat")));

        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Message message = new Message();

                message.setMessage(editText.getText().toString());
                message.setAuthor("Name");

                firebase.child("Chat").push().setValue(message);

                editText.setText("");
            }
        });

    }

        @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN)
        public void make (View view){

            Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayNotification.class);
            PendingIntent pending = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);

            Notification notifications = new Notification.Builder(this)
                    .setContentTitle("New notification like message from")
                    .setContentText("Hii").setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification)
                    .setContentIntent(pending)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.reply, "Reply", pending)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.cancel, "cancel", pending)
                    .addAction(R.drawable.settings, "settings", pending).build();

            NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
            notifications.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
            manager.notify(0, notifications);

        }
}
```

**EDIT2:**

Android Documentation says:

> **addAction(int icon, CharSequence title, PendingIntent intent)**
>
> *This method was deprecated in API level 23. Use **addAction(Action)** instead.*

so use this

```
addAction(new Notification.Action(R.drawable.reply, "Reply", pending));
```

instead

```
addAction(R.drawable.reply, "Reply", pending)
```

Comment: what code for supporting pre-jellybean device? am not familiar

Comment: what is your minSdkVersion ?

Comment: I mean 16 ,i am using minsdk 16

Comment: if minsdk 16 then you can remove else condtion or you can try edited answer if minsdk is less than 16

Comment: the addAction is deprecated